# Sql criteria filter as comma del string

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have a stored proc defines as follows.

```
PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetSales](@dateFilter nvarchar(50))
AS
BEGIN
     SELECT sum(Amount)
     FROM Sales
     WHERE SalesDate in (' + @dateFilter  + ')
     group by SalesDate 

END
```

to select data from this table

```
Id SalesDate     Amount
1   Apr-2010       40.25
2   May-2010       12.10
3   Jun-2010        2.50
```

I used Execute sp command and passed this text 'Mar-2010','Apr-2010'

The call generated this code and retured nothing.

```
DECLARE @return_value int

EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[GetSales]
    @dateFilter = N'''Mar-2010'',''Apr-2010'''

SELECT  'Return Value' = @return_value
```

But this (call statement X) works

```
 SELECT sum(Amount)
     FROM Sales
     WHERE SalesDate in ('Mar-2010','Apr-2010')
     group by SalesDate
```

returning

```
(No column name)
40.25
```

How can I fromat the parameter filter so the stored proc uses it as statement X above?

Answer (score 1):

The dynamic sql solution is messy and hard to maintain. IMO it's better to parse the list into a temp table or variable and join it.

[Creating a SQL table from a comma concatenated list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3516064/creating-a-sql-table-from-a-comma-concatenated-list/3516162#3516162)

Answer (score 0):

You have two options. Either create the entire SQL as nvarchar and use `EXEC(statement)` or parse the delimited input string into a temp table and then use `WHERE SalesDate in(SELECT value FROM #t)`

E.g.

`EXEC(N'SELECT sum(Amount) FROM Sales WHERE SalesDate in ('+ @DateFilter + N') group by SalesDate')`

This approach can provide a loophole for SQL Injection attacks.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetSales
    @dateFilter nvarchar(50)
AS
BEGIN
   execute('SELECT sum(Amount) FROM Sales WHERE SalesDate in (' + @dateFilter + ') group by SalesDate');
END
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer from http://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql-2005.html

ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[iter$simple_intlist_to_tbl](@list nvarchar(MAX))
RETURNS  @tbl TABLE (PeriodFilter nvarchar(10)) AS
BEGIN
   DECLARE @pos        int,
           @nextpos    int,
           @valuelen   int

SELECT @pos = 0, @nextpos = 1

WHILE @nextpos > 0
   BEGIN
      SELECT @nextpos = charindex(',', @list, @pos + 1)
      SELECT @valuelen = CASE WHEN @nextpos > 0
                              THEN @nextpos
                              ELSE len(@list) + 1
                         END - @pos - 1
      INSERT @tbl (PeriodFilter)
         VALUES (substring(@list, @pos + 1, @valuelen))
      SELECT @pos = @nextpos
   END
   RETURN
END

this proc 
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetSales](@dateFilter nvarchar(50))
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
     SELECT sum(Amount)
     FROM Sales
     WHERE SalesDate in ( select * from dbo.iter$simple_intlist_to_tbl(@dateFilter))
     group by SalesDate

END

the cal

DECLARE @return_value int

EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[GetSales]
        @dateFilter = N'May-2010,Apr-2010'

SELECT  'Return Value' = @return_value

GO