# Sql server, sql query, "IN" statement not working

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query where comma seperated barcodes are provided. But for some unknown reason it is not working:

Below is the code that does not work

```
DECLARE @txtBarcode VARCHAR(MAX)

SET @txtBarcode = '2003824,2003825';

SELECT [Scan_Curr_Location] 
FROM BarCode_Location_Current 
WHERE Scan_Curr_BarCodeNo IN (@txtBarcode) 
ORDER BY [Scan_Curr_BarCodeNo] ASC
```

However when I change it to a single barcode it works fine i.e:

```
SET @txtBarcode = '2003824';
```

Please advice.

Thanks!

Comment: See the accepted answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3516064/creating-a-sql-table-from-a-comma-concatenated-list.  I always loved the way this goes about solving the issue.

Answer (score 3):

`IN` does not work like that.
It takes a comma separated list, not a string with comma separated values.

This would work:

```
SELECT [Scan_Curr_Location] FROM BarCode_Location_Current WHERE Scan_Curr_BarCodeNo 
IN ('2003824', '2003825') ORDER BY [Scan_Curr_BarCodeNo] ASC
```

Answer (score 1):

As documented here http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_in.asp :-

> The IN operator allows you to specify multiple values in a WHERE
>   clause.
>
> SQL IN Syntax
>
> SELECT column_name(s)
>   FROM table_name
>   WHERE column_name IN(value1,value2,...);

so in your case you should make it comma separated like this:

```
SELECT [Scan_Curr_Location] 
FROM BarCode_Location_Current 
WHERE Scan_Curr_BarCodeNo IN ('2003824', '2003825') 
ORDER BY [Scan_Curr_BarCodeNo] ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to use LIKE instead of IN :

```
DECLARE @txtBarcode VARCHAR(MAX)

SET @txtBarcode = '2003824,2003825';

SELECT [Scan_Curr_Location] 
FROM BarCode_Location_Current 
WHERE @txtBarcode LIKE '%' + Scan_Curr_BarCodeNo + '%'
ORDER BY [Scan_Curr_BarCodeNo] ASC
```

Note the wildcards '%' around the column you are searching...